# Spark - SparkSession access issue

Tags: apache-spark, kotlin

I have a problem similar to one in
[Spark java.lang.NullPointerException Error when filter spark data frame on inside foreach iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53577716/spark-java-lang-nullpointerexception-error-when-filter-spark-data-frame-on-insid/53582406#53582406)

```
    String_Lines.foreachRDD{line ->
            line.foreach{x ->
                // JSON to DF Example
                val sparkConfig = SparkConf().setAppName("JavaKinesisWordCountASL").setMaster("local[*]").
                                  set("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///C:/tmp")
                val spark = SparkSession.builder().config(sparkConfig).orCreate

                val outer_jsonData = Arrays.asList(x)
                val outer_anotherPeopleDataset = spark.createDataset(outer_jsonData, Encoders.STRING())
                spark.read().json(outer_anotherPeopleDataset).createOrReplaceTempView("jsonInnerView")
                spark.sql("select name, address.city, address.state from jsonInnerView").show(false)
                println("Current String #"+ x)
        }
    }
```

@thebluephantom did explain it to the point. I have my code in foreachRDD now, but still it doesn't work. This is Kotlin and I am running it in my local laptop with IntelliJ. Somehow it's not picking sparksession as I understand after reading all blogs. If I delete "spark.read and spark.sql", everything else works OK. What should I do to fix this?

Comment: This is the error message # 

22/02/26 16:50:05 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; the static sql configurations will not take effect.
22/02/26 16:50:05 WARN SparkSession$Builder: Using an existing SparkSession; some spark core configurations may not take effect.
2/02/26 16:50:05 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 4.0 (TID 4)
java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

> If I delete "spark.read and spark.sql", everything else works OK

If you delete those, you're not actually making Spark do anything, only defining what Spark actions *should* happen (Spark actions are lazy)

> Somehow it's not picking sparksession as I understand

It's "picking it up" just fine. The error is happening because it's picking up a *brand new* SparkSession. You should already have defined one of these outside of the forEachRDD method, but if you try to reuse it, you might run into different issues

---

Assuming `String_Lines` is already a Dataframe. There's no point in looping over all of its RDD data and trying to create brand new SparkSession. Or if it's a DStream, convert it to Streaming Dataframe instead...

That being said, you should be able to immediately select data from it

```
// unclear what the schema of this is 
val selected = String_Lines.selectExpr("name", "address.city", "address.state")
selected.show(false)
```

You may need to add a `get_json_object` function in there if you're trying to parse strings to JSON

Answer (score 0):

I am able to solve it finally.
I modified code like this.... Its clean and working.

This is **String_Lines** data type

```
val String_Lines: JavaDStream<String>
        String_Lines.foreachRDD { x ->
            val df = spark.read().json(x)
            df.printSchema()
            df.show(2,false)
        }
```

Thanks,
Chandra